# Postgres digest() behaving differently with string concat versus bytea concat?

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to replicate some postgres code that uses the pgcrypto digest function into Java.
I was assuming that the following two commands would generate the same result:

```
select digest('Hi there' || 'Abc' || decode('00','hex'), 'sha256');
select digest('Hi thereAbc' || decode('00','hex'), 'sha256');
```

However, this is not the case... Those two commands produce different results:

```
postgres=# select digest('Hi there' || 'Abc' || decode('00','hex'), 'sha256');
                           digest                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 \xd4321124595112a1e8cd8d90709b8cf58aabdd14ad09ff972e6fe0f75bd25d97

postgres=# select digest('Hi thereAbc' || decode('00','hex'), 'sha256');
                           digest                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 \xf2477e4fcaf6ea37ab985fc1fa029a99fb331657e7a3e349ffc844e9d068f250
```

Any idea why those give different results?

On the other hand, doing the concatenation without the bytes on the end works as expected:

```
postgres=# select digest('Hi thereAbc', 'sha256');
                          digest                              
------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x3e1d7fed02b93824aba03835b93314f0293026276c8e50f4b70935f988e0c0bf

postgres=# select digest('Hi there' || 'Abc', 'sha256');
                          digest                              
------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x3e1d7fed02b93824aba03835b93314f0293026276c8e50f4b70935f988e0c0bf
```

(1 row)

Thanks!

Edit: Answer update
As per @ferhat elmas's answer, the two inputs to digest are as follows:

```
select 'Hi thereAbc' || decode('00', 'hex');
 \x486920746865726541626300

select 'Hi there' || 'Abc' || decode('00', 'hex');
Hi thereAbc\x00
```

I was assuming those two values were equivalent - just one as bytes and the other as a string, but they are not - the backslash x 0 0 are literal characters in the string, not a single 0 byte.

Comment: Can you try with `('Hi there' || 'Abc') || decode('00','hex')`?

Comment: Tried it out...
select digest( ('Hi there' || 'Abc' ) || decode('00','hex'), 'sha256');
produces the same result as without the ( ):
 \xd4321124595112a1e8cd8d90709b8cf58aabdd14ad09ff972e6fe0f75bd25d97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because how postgres resolves unknown types.

```
select 'Hi there' || 'Abc' || decode('00', 'hex')
       unknown || unknown || bytea -- see the snippet below from the docs
       string || bytea
       string
```

From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html):

> In this case there is no initial hint for which type to use, since no types are specified in the query. So, the parser looks for all candidate operators and finds that there are candidates accepting both string-category and bit-string-category inputs. Since string category is preferred when available, that category is selected, and then the preferred type for strings, text, is used as the specific type to resolve the unknown-type literals as.

```
select 'Hi thereAbc' || decode('00', 'hex')
       unknown || bytea -- this step is hinted by the known type
       string
```

That's why in one case, the text is encoded as hex then concatenated but in the other case, they are concatenated directly because one case has the known type while the other hasn't.

To ensure consistency, it's better to provide type hints.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to change the postgres code, as we have lots of data using this already.
Do you think that the data being passed to `digest` is different in the two cases, or do you think that `digest(text)` uses a different algorithm from `digest(bytea)`, or something else going on?

Comment: Inputs passed to digest are different. If you can ensure that values have proper type hints  (`::text` or `::bytea`), then it will be associative and should be fine.